# Query inside subscription is not getting called on tab change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, react-apollo

My query is getting only on first initialization but on change of one tab from another tab not getting called. These tabs are dynamically generated and once the tab is initialized query gets called and then if you switch between the same tabs query is not getting called and I cannot call the query above subscription. Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

```
 <Subscription
        subscription={QGPQL.getColumns(base.uniq_id, table.sheet_uniq_id)}
        errorPolicy="all"
        onSubscriptionData={(data) => {this.onFetchColumn(data)}}
      >
        {({ loading: loadingC, error: errorC, data: columns }) => {
          if (loadingC) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
          }
          if (errorC) {
            console.warn("Error", errorC);
            return <p>Error: {errorC}</p>;
          }
          if (!columns) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <Query
              query={QGPQL.getData(
                base.uniq_id,
                table.sheet_uniq_id,
                columns[`v_spec`]
              )}
              errorPolicy="all"
              onCompleted={(data) => {this.onDataFetch(data)}}
            >
              {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <p>Loading...</p>;
                }
                if (error) {
                  console.warn("Error", error);
                  return <p>Error: {`${error}`}</p>;
                }
                if (!data) {
                  return null;
                }
                let currentTime = data["server_time"][0].value;
                let temp = {};
                temp[`${base.uniq_id}_v_data`] = data[
                  `${base.uniq_id}_v_data`
                ].map(row => {
                  return row.odata;
                });
)}}
</Query>
)
}}
</Subscription>
```